# How can I adapt form (relaive auth form) in html

Tags: python, html, django

I want to create a login form using `django` but I don't know how adapt `django` form in `html`.

when i use only `{{form.username}}`, that is good working, but that method can't applying CSS style.

```
<div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-label-group">
            <input type="text" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" value ="{{form.username}}" }}">
            <label for="inputEmail">Account</label>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the field attributes inside **init** method of your form class. E.x:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs={
        'class':'class_name',
        }
```